# The language - Spanish (Colombia) is not available

Tags: elementary-website, translation

I'm trying to contribute to Elementary with spanish translations but I want add a Spanish (Colombia) language but I don't have permissions. Could you please help me adding the Spanish (Colombia)?.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

You can contribute to the translation of Elementary OS [here](https://l10n.elementary.io/languages/)

In the list there is at least ***Spanish (American Latin)***

you have the documentation [here](https://docs.weblate.org/en/weblate-3.7.1/index.html)

Comment: Yes, I know, but each country use the same word for different things, I’m trying to generate a Colombian Community for elementary and the Colombian Localization is required if it’s posible.

Comment: I think you can contact them via the contact form to propose to add Columbia to the list

Comment: yes, I try it yesterday but weblate generate a error.

Answer (score 0):

Please do not contribute to further duplication of the volunteer localization efforts. The actual intent is to provide a single, generic translation to Spanish, without localisms. The fact that the Website project at Weblate has multiple Spanish locales enabled is unfortunate, and IMHO those should be deleted.